# How to capture the values of a list inside json using regex

Tags: java, regex, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a json part of which contains this:
{"tokenType":"email","tokenList":["token1","token2","token3","token4"]}

I have a flink job which is logging the payload it receives from kafka and I need to mask these token values(email/phone number) in my logs. For that we are using a utility which will mask first x characters for all the captured groups(starting from index 1).

My problem is that I can not find a regex which will capture all these tokens when the list can be of variable length.

I can write regex that can capture the whole list but the issue is that the whole match will be considered a captured group and the first x characters will be masked.
I want my log to look like this, for x = 3:
{"tokenType":"email","tokenList":["***en1","***en2","***en3","***en4"]}

I need my regex to capture the values of these tokens.

Comment: Why use a regex at all? _Parse the JSON_ then deal with it in a structured way.

Comment: We had to mask payload for multiple types of payloads. So instead of parsing just doing string replacement using regex looked easier. Got stuck with this one

Comment: I assure you, parsing JSON is always easier, safer and more robust than writing a regex that could break at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a one-to-many mapping, you'd likely want to accomplish this via a [**`flatMap()`**](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/overview/#flatmap) function to support creating multiple elements from a single one. Since your payload is already taking in JSON-based strings, you could parse this as a structured JSON object and then extract the elements you need and send those downstream.

Something like:

```
// Function to take in a single JSON string and output multiple string elements
class TokenMaskingFunction: FlatMapFunction<String, String>{
    override fun flatMap(input: String, collector: Collector<String>) {
        try {
            // Construct your JSON node
            val structuredJson: JsonNode = mapper.readTree(input)
    
            // Capture your tokens
            val tokens: JsonNode = structuredJson.get("tokenList")
            if (tokens.isArray) {
                for (token in tokens) {
                    // Extract and mask your token before sending downstream
                    val maskedToken = maskFunction(token.toString())
                    collector.collect(maskedToken)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Handle accordingly / log / ignore
        }
    }

    private fun mask(token: String): String { 
        // Do your masking here
    }

    companion object {
        // Define some static JSON parser here (static is important)
        val mapper = ObjectMapper()
    }
}
```

And then you'd just use that after mapping from your source of JSON strings:

```
streamEnv
    .fromSource(yourJsonStringSource)
    .flatMap(TokenMaskingFunction())
    .process(...)
```

Comment: We are sending all the elements downstream. Our payload is also xml for some jobs. We are then also publishing to kafka/MQ. 
We created a wrapper over slf4j logger  to mask the string according to regex.

Comment: Something like LOG.infoMask(payload) and then inside this it is masking and then logging

Comment: But I cannot send masked tokens downstream, need them for api calls. I only want to mask in the log statement

Comment: Yeah, the same logic would apply. You could easily just log within that `mask()` function for any transforms/logging if necessary. Or just replace it with a log entirely. 

If you are handling XML and JSON from the same source, you could just add some type of filter to handle each types accordingly or if they are all strings to begin with just apply the necessary logic to parse XML or JSON based on some condition.

Comment: As far as sending them downstream, you could either issue the API calls within this function or create a separate function that handles issuing those API calls and accepts the output from this one. There are lots of ways to handle this, which may vary depending on your volume, API, etc. If your API supports it, it might be worth leveraging state to bulk/batch the API calls as well, all will just depend on your use-case/volume.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a crude solution using Pattern class. It is not very efficient but works for the given example.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String val = " {\"tokenType\":\"email\",\"tokenList\":[\"token1\",\"token2\",\"token3\",\"token4\"]}";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\G(?!^)|\"tokenList\":\\[)\"(?<elem>[^\"]*)\",?");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(val);
        int n  = 3;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while (m.find()) {
            String elem = m.group("elem");
            if (elem != null) {
                m.appendReplacement(builder, m.group().replace(elem, "*".repeat(n).concat(elem.substring(n))));
            }
        }
        m.appendTail(builder);
        System.out.println(builder);
    }
```